# jQuery DataTable: How to chain rows() methods to apply multiple conditions?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I wonder why  table.rows([selector1]).rows([selector2])  doesn't return the rows which satisfies the both selector1 and selector2.

For example, the following code ignores the first condtion {selected:true}.

```
table.rows({selected:true}).rows((index, row, node)=>{return row[3]<30}).deselect()
```

table source: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html

I could solve the problem by combining the two conitions into one rows(), but I still wonder why chaining rows() doesn't work as I intended.

Rows() methods returns DataTables.Api and it provides the ability to chain according to the reference.
https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Api

```
table.rows((index, row, node)=>{return $(node).hasClass("selected") && row[3]<=30}).deselect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

When you use `rows({selected:true})`, that does return an API instance (as you note) - but that instance still contains all the original data, and just captures the selected row IDs as *additional* metadata.

---

**Longer Answer**

Let's assume you have selected one or more rows in a DataTable using the [select extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/).

Then, you execute the following:

```
table.rows({selected:true})
```

As you state in the question, and as described in the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()), this returns a:

> "DataTables API instance with selected rows"

But that does *not* mean a DataTables API which now contains *only* those rows.

It actually means a DataTables API with some additional metadata which describes the set of selected rows.

All of the original data (selected and unselected) is still stored in that API instance - and will still be used when you perform an additional chained `rows()` call.

That is why it appears as if the first `rows()` call in your example chain is ignored - because it effectively *is* ignored.

(This may appear counter-intuitive if you assume the returned API instance is just a filtered version of the original.)

---

You can explore this further.

I have chosen a demo which does not use the select extension, for simplicity. But the same concepts apply:

```js
var dataSet = [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "Donna Snider",
    "position": "Customer Support",
    "salary": "$112,000",
    "start_date": "2011/01/25",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4226"
  },
  {
    "id": "567",
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  },
  {
    "id": "632",
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2008/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  },
  {
    "id": "987",
    "name": "Brielle Williamson",
    "position": "Integration Specialist",
    "salary": "$372,000",
    "start_date": "2012/12/02",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4804"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{
        title: "ID",
        data: "id"
      },
      {
        title: "Name",
        data: "name"
      },
      {
        title: "Office",
        data: "office"
      },
      {
        title: "Position",
        data: "position"
      },
      {
        title: "Start date",
        data: "start_date"
      },
      {
        title: "Extn.",
        data: "extn"
      },
      {
        title: "Salary",
        data: "salary"
      }
    ]

  });

  var selected1 = table.rows([1, 2, 3]).data().toArray();
  console.log(selected1);

  // expect this to find no data, but it finds Tiger Nixon:
  var selected2 = table.rows([1, 2, 3]).rows([0]).data().toArray();
  console.log(selected2);

  // the extra metadata for the initially selected row IDs:
  console.log(table.rows([1, 2, 3])[0]);

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

When I execute the following:

```
var selected1 = table.rows( [1,2,3] ).data().toArray();
console.log( selected1 );
```

it returns three records as expected for Donna, Cedric, and Airi, since those are the records with row indexes of 1, 2, and 3.

But when I execute the following:

```
var selected2 = table.rows( [1,2,3] ).rows( [0] ).data().toArray();
console.log( selected2 );
```

I would expect it to return no data - because row index zero is not contained in row indexes 1, 2, or 3. Instead I get Tiger Nixon (row index 0 from the *original* table).

---

You can see where the extra metadata is stored for `table.rows( [1,2,3] )`:

```
console.log( table.rows( [1,2,3] )[0] );
```

This returns the DataTables index values of the selected rows:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

---

So, yes, you can definitely chain API calls; but how they operate may not be what you expect, if you are chaining calls which appear to filter or narrow down the original data set.

I can't speculate on why DataTables is built this way. You can ask in the DataTables [forum](https://datatables.net/forums/) for a better answer than I could give you here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! 
I have better understanding of datatable now.